# Sonata Admin Bundle remove routeCollection roles

Tags: symfony, roles, configure, sonata-admin

I'm using Sonata Admin Bundle and I'm having some troubles with the function:

```
function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection){ }
```

The function works correctly if I write a simple:

```
$collection->remove('create');
```

But what I'm triying to do is to remove some routes depending on the role of the user connected, so I tried:

```
$seguridad = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context');
if ($seguridad->getToken()->getUser() != "anon."){
    if ( !$seguridad->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')  ) {
        $collection->remove('create');
    }
}
```

But logged as Admin I get the error:
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Route "admin_sademer_core_MIENTITY_create" does not exist.") in SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_admin_list.html.twig at line 31.

It's like in some moment the Sonata remove the route create I before enter in the dashboard, and then when I enter in the dashboard I try to enter in the route create but the route is already removed. But I'm not sure what is happening.

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#configuration, there is actually a built-in way to do this.

Comment: I saw this page, but it's not  clear how to attach each permission to each user/role with each entity.
Because the documentation only show how can you declare diferent permissions, but not how to declare which permission have each role with each entity.

Answer (score 2):

I just did it different way, Just overridden isGranted() in entitAdmin.php file.  Then you can check permission depending on user roles. But it served our purpose. If we want to use $collection->remove('create'), we can't do that since no way to call the method ("configureRoutes()") in the application run time. Only calling that method ("configureRoutes()") while cache is creating.

```
 /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isGranted($name, $object = null)
{
    $user = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    switch ($name) {
        case "CREATE":
            if (!$user->hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                return false;
            }
        default:
            return true;
    }
}
```